# JS button dont seem to be working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why is my navigation menu slider button not working? 
I have included Jquery already.. can anyone point out my mistake?

code sample without jquery cdn is from 
http://codepen.io/birdsong/pen/DxajG

also how do i create another version of right slider tab? i think its pretty simple? copying pasting and changing variables?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="navContainer">
            <ul>
                <li>Home</li>
                <li>Page 1</li>
                <li>Page 2</li>
                <li>Page 3</li>
                <li>Page 4</li>
                <li>Page 5</li>
                <li>Page 6</li>
                <li>Page 7</li>
            </ul>
            <div id="contentContainer">
                <header>
                    <div href="" onclick="openNav();" class="button"></div>
                </header>
                <div id="placeCheckHere"></div>
            </div>
        </div>              
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            function closeNav() {
                $('#contentContainer').removeClass('moveOut').addClass('moveIn');
                $('#navContainer ul').removeClass('slideIn').addClass('slideOut');
                $('#placeCheckHere').html("");
            }
            function openNav() { 
                $('#contentContainer').removeClass('moveIn').addClass('moveOut');
                $('#navContainer ul').removeClass('slideOut').addClass('slideIn');
                $('#placeCheckHere').html("<div id='checkNavDiv' onclick='closeNav();'></div>");  
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: codepen link does not work for me, will not load. Try using http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I don't understand, the menu is opening just fine. What is it exactly you're trying to do?

Comment: @josh no. the menu doesnt work. index.php+style.css

Comment: @user2947950 The menu works just fine for me: http://i.imgur.com/J9TdeFC.png

Comment: It's ok on Chrome but not on Firefox

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is that you try to reproduce the example but having issues with the css which is `scss`.
So here is the complete code of the example and the same working the other way around (roughly),

**left to right**

**css**

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
}

#navContainer {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  display: block;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #eee;
}

#contentContainer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px black;
}

#checkNavDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #bbb;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.button {
  width: 33px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("http://birdsongmedia.com/images/menu-icon1.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: 19px;
}

article {
  padding: 10px;
}

.moveOut {
  -webkit-animation: moveContentOut 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(85%, 0);
}

.moveIn {
  -webkit-animation: moveContentIn 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(85%, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(85%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: navSlideIn 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.slideOut {
  -webkit-animation: navSlideOut 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes navSlideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes navSlideOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0);
  }
}
```

**right to left**

### http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bGyag

**css**

```
    * {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Helvetica';
  font-weight: 300;
}

#navContainer {
  width: 85%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-right: 15%;
  display: block;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 10px;
}

#navContainer ul {
  position: relative;
  left: 110%;
}

li {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #eee;
}

#contentContainer {
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: #ddd;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px black;
}

#checkNavDiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #bbb;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.button {
  width: 33px;
  height: 24px;
  background: url("http://birdsongmedia.com/images/menu-icon1.png");
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  top: 13px;
  left: -19px;
  float: right;
}

article {
  padding: 10px;
}

.moveOut {
  -webkit-animation: moveContentOut 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-85%, 0);
}

.moveIn {
  -webkit-animation: moveContentIn 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-85%, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes moveContentIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-85%, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

.slideIn {
  -webkit-animation: navSlideIn 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
}

.slideOut {
  -webkit-animation: navSlideOut 0.35s ease;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0);
}

@-webkit-keyframes navSlideIn {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes navSlideOut {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(0, 0);
  }

  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate(-40px, 0);
  }
}
```

**common html and js**

```
<div id="navContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Page 1</li>
    <li>Page 2</li>
    <li>Page 3</li>
    <li>Page 4</li>
    <li>Page 5</li>
    <li>Page 6</li>
    <li>Page 7</li>
  </ul>
  <div id="contentContainer">
    <header>
      <div href="" onclick="openNav();" class="button"></div>
    </header>
    <div id="placeCheckHere"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js**

```
function closeNav() {
 $('#contentContainer').removeClass('moveOut').addClass('moveIn');
  $('#navContainer ul').removeClass('slideIn').addClass('slideOut');
  $('#placeCheckHere').html("");
}

function openNav() { 
    $('#contentContainer').removeClass('moveIn').addClass('moveOut');
    $('#navContainer ul').removeClass('slideOut').addClass('slideIn');
    $('#placeCheckHere').html("<div id='checkNavDiv' onclick='closeNav();'></div>");  
}
```

Comment: it works! i think its CSS problem... is there anyway i can combine them into one?